# How can I compare the session value to current user id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

1. How can I compare the session value with the current user id.
2. To display only the record of that user who is login.
3. Here I join three tables to make this view.
4. `if (Session["UserId"] == Model.userAccount.UserId)` Here is the code where I got error.

[image]

code:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.BookingViewModel>

  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   }

   <h2 id="h1">Bookings Detail</h2>

   <p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Add New Booking", "Create")
   </p>
   @if (Session["User"] == null)
   {
   Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "Account"));
   }
   else if (Session["LoginRole"].ToString() == "Admin")
   {
   <table class="table">
   <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.taxi.TaxiName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userAccount.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.BookingStartDateandTime)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.BookingEndDateandTime)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.UserContactNo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.UserStartingLoaction)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.UserDistination)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bookingStatus.Status)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.taxi.TaxiName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userAccount.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.BookingStartDateandTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.BookingEndDateandTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.UserContactNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.UserStartingLoaction)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.UserDistination)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.bookingStatus.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.booking.BookingId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.booking.BookingId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.booking.BookingId })
        </td>
    </tr>
   }

   </table>
   }
   else if (Session["UserId"] == Model.userAccount.UserId) 

   {

    <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.taxi.TaxiName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userAccount.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.BookingStartDateandTime)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.BookingEndDateandTime)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.UserContactNo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.UserStartingLoaction)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.booking.UserDistination)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bookingStatus.Status)
    </th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in @Model)
    {
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.taxi.TaxiName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userAccount.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.BookingStartDateandTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.BookingEndDateandTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.UserContactNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.UserStartingLoaction)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.booking.UserDistination)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.bookingStatus.Status)
        </td>
       </tr>
     }

    </table>
   }
```

Comment: Try reading the error message.

Comment: What do you think `Model.userAccount` means?

Comment: May I ask, which error you got? Most users asking a question here do have an error of some sort, but posting the actual exception message does help us a lot in figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: Please post the code for type `BookingViewModel`.

Comment: `Model` is a _collection_ of `BookingViewModel`s. So you need to either change the view to be for a _single_ `BookingViewModel` or choose one from the collection.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is also the type mismatch between Session["userId"] and his userAccount.id. So you probably need to do conversion with `Convert.ToInt32(Session["UerId"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is an enumeration of `BookingViewModel`, so this statement will fail:

```
else if (Session["UserId"] == Model.userAccount.UserId)
```

Because `Model` is a group of items, not just one item.

What you need to do instead is look for the user account and display it:

```
//This is the else statement that was giving you trouble. Change it to:
else
{
    string sessionId = Session["UserId"] as string;
    var account = Model.FirstOrDefault(a => a.userAccount.UserId == sessionId);
    if(account != null)
    {
        //Use your display code here
    }
    else
    {
        //Figure out what to do if for some odd reason, you can't find it.
    }
}
```

The quick code sample assumes `userId` is a `string`. Use casting as needed.

I would suggest creating a partial view to display the fields as opposed to code repetition.

Comment: bro this is my login code  
                var usr = db.UserAccounts.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    Session["user"] = usr.ToString();
                    Session["UserId"] = usr.UserId.ToString();

                    if (usr.UserRole == true)
                    {
                        Session["LoginRole"] = "Admin";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session["LoginRole"] = "User";
                    }

Comment: @Farman: Please don't post long code as a comment. Add it to your question instead.

Comment: @JuanR I am trying to compare my session ID with the user ID and I cannot access `Model.FirstOrDefault...` in my **Edit.cshtml** page. I need to redirect the user if he's not an admin or the actual user of the account's edit page. Am I missing something? [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/H0xvyVa.png)

Comment: @pensum: It looks like you are missing the namespace for the `FirstOrDefault` extension. Adding `@using System.Linq` to the top of your view might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the `User` property of your `ViewPage`. Do not save user ID in session
Suppose you have authenticated user and he has role & identity.

```
public class MyPrincipal: IPrincipal 
{
    private MyIdentity _identity;
    private string[] _roles;

    public MyPrincipal(MyIdentity identity, string[] roles) 
    {
       _identity = identity;
       _roles = roles;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) 
    {
      return _roles?.Length > 0 && _roles.Contains(role);
    }

    IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity 
    {
       get 
       {
          return _identity;
       } 
    }

    public MyIdentity Identity 
    {
       get { return _identity;}
    }

    // User ID you need
    public int UserId 
    {
       get 
       {
          return Identity.UserId;
       }
    }
}
somewhere in your code 
@{
    int currentUserId = (User as MyPrincipal).UserId; 
}   
@if (currentUserId == Model.userId) 
{
     // this will be executed personally per executing user
}
```

Comment: Can I use Iprincipal in myprincipal without Identity because I didn't using Identity for authentication. I have used only session for login.
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    Session["user"] = usr.ToString()
                    Session["UserId"] = usr.UserId.ToString()
                    if (usr.UserRole == true)
                    {
                     Session["LoginRole"] = "Admin"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Session["LoginRole"] = "User"
                    }